# OpenSSH for Windows stopped working

Tags: ssh, putty, windows-server-2008, openssh

I'm trying to connect with putty from a Windows 10 VM to a Windows Server 2008. Port 22 is open on the server. I keep getting this error in Windows Server: "OpenSSH for Windows stopped working", and putty: "Network error: Software caused connection abort". Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: It may be useful to name your virtualization software and host machine/OS in the question.

Comment: I am using VMWare Fusion Pro 11.5.3 and my host OS is Mac